# Not able to classify hand drawn image using coreML

Tags: swift, core-image, coreml

I am trying to classify hand-drawn images using coreML. my model is able to classify the image taken from the gallery. But when I pass the hand-drawn image taken using "UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext", my model is failing to classify.someone please help me find the bug?

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bottomImageView.frame.size)
 bottomImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
 bottomImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I am using the above code to get the image drawn in the current context.

```
let image = bottomImageView.image 
   if  let reqImage = image.cgImage {
        do {
            let model1 = try VNCoreMLModel(for: ImageClassifier().model)
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model1, completionHandler: myResultsMethod)
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: reqImage)
            try handler.perform([request])
            
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
 func myResultsMethod(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
            else { fatalError("vision is not able to process the image") }
        for classification in results {
            if classification.confidence > 0.9 {
                classifier.text = "I think this is a \(classification.identifier)."
                break
            }
            else {
                classifier.text = "I am sorry, I can't predict. train me more."
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I am using this code to get the classifier results by vision.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your hand-drawn image looks different somehow than the images that work successfully.

In this case it is useful to look at the actual image that is being sent to Core ML. You can use the CheckInputImage code from https://github.com/hollance/coreml-survival-guide for this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, when I save my hand-drawn image to the iPhone gallery and select it from the gallery as the input image to the classifier, then it is absolutely classifying fine.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant here. It just means the iPhone gallery is able to read your image and possibly convert it into a compatible format. It doesn't mean Core ML will be able to do the same thing.